# Repositories design confusion

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have the following repositories:

- `EmployeeRepository`
- `DocumentRepository`
- `CourseRepository`
- `LeaveRepository`

We have a requirement now to add a new business object called `BusinessTripBidding` which allows employees to bid for different business trips and so. Anyway, The problem is when returning the list of `Bidders` I need to include information from the all above mentioned repositories as the business requires, and then I generate a new object and return a list (in my business object), something like this:

```
IEnumerable<BidderInfo> GetBiddersInfo(int tripId)
{
    List<Bidder> bidders = _bidderRepository.GetListByTripId(tripId);

    List<Course> courses = _courseRepository
         .GetListByEmployeeId(bidders.Select(b => b.EmployeeId).AsEnumerable());

    List<Document> passports = _documentRepository
         .GetListByEmployeeId(bidders.Select(b => b.EmployeeId).AsEnumerable(), DocumentType.Passport);

    List<Leave> leaves = ...........

    var biddersInfo = new List<BidderInfo>();
    foreach(Bidder b in bidders)
    {
        var bi = new BidderInfo();
        bi.Courses = courses.Where(c => c.EmployeeId == b.EmployeeId).ToList();
        bi.Passport = passports.FirstOrDefault(p => p.EmployeeId == b.EmployeeId);

        bi.ComingLeave = .........

        // the same for the rest of the repositories

        biddersInfo.Add(bi);
    }
    return biddersInfo;
}
```

Beside the multiple calls to the db, and beside the loop, it would be much easier if I create a new repository only responsible to create this `BidderInfo` in one single query, let's call it `BidderInfoGeneratorRepository` then inject this repository in the constructor of the business object.

Now, should I keep thing as I am doing currently (multiple db calls) but things look right;
or should I create another repository and pass it to the business object to make things a bit faster? what is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice depends on the amount and the change speed of the data. 
If your data is only a few hundred/thousands rows and changing slowly, you can cache it in the app and invalidate the cache upon updates. 
When your data is too big to store it in the memory, I would avoid the multiple calls when possible without a big increase in code complexity.

Comment: `without a big increase in code complexity` that's the question.. how? is my approach correct by creating a new repository for that purpose?

Comment: In this case yes, you can create a new repository.
Two small things: you are filtering your courses two times when I see it correctly. Second: I would not call ToList() on setting bi.Courses as it drops the performance.

Comment: The first filter is to get the list of courses for all the employees in this request, the GetByEmployeeId has an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<string>`. The second filter is to get the specific employee.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid tight coupling between repositories.

Although I'm a big fan of *domain first*, *data agnosticism* and other good practices to implement DDD-based architectures, I would say that you can still retain these features while you don't need to couple your repositories that way.

BTW, if I correctly understood your approach, I find there's a design flaw in your reasoning: `BidderInfo` is a *domain object*, but it's not a persistent object, isn't it? Repositories are meant to work together with the data mapping layer to either persist domain changes and provide agnostic querying.

My first conclusion reading your code is that the whole method should go into a *domain service* where you may inject as many repositories as you want because it's the right place to do so.

Secondly, there's something that could simplify things even more and it might be your definitive solution: **why don't you turn `BidderInfo` into a persistable object?**

I shouldn't be guessing wrongly if I think that you're using an OR/M, right? Hence, if you configure it in the right way, you can persist `BidderInfo` and get it automatically populated in a single query (or who knows, but it'll be an OR/M optimization role). Therefore, you'll create the whole `BidderInfoRepository` on which you'll simply implement a `GetById(...)` that will call the OR/M behind the scenes.

Otherwise, you should put this code into the *service layer*.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, the idea came beacuse there's a good performance gain, I thought it's even allowed to put some of the logic in a stored procedure if that will give u a good performance gain.. Regarding BidderInfo, it's an object that can't be saved in the database directly, it gets it's properties from many other tables as shown. Consider it as a report sort of thing.. confused here :)

Comment: @Him Hey ;) Read [this article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) composed by Martin Fowler. After you've already read it, we can continue the discussion!

Comment: you have made me read about CQRS for the past hour now. It's a really cool system but it's impossible for now to refactor an old project. Thanks for the tips though :)

Comment: @Him You're not able to implement an SQL Server job that might drop `BidderInfo ` so you can map the domain to some dedicated tables?

Comment: I have decided to inject the other repositories needed to create object in the service layer. The performance drop is not really bad, a few milliseconds after some testing. This way I made sure things are clean and I also have a simple caching mechanism (REDIS) that helped. Keeping things simple is the best thing for now. But indeed this query command separation looks promising. It's just perfect considering the fact that I can create as much DTOs as the project needs without violating and pattern.. the real pain in the ass code can be kept in the command side.

Comment: I am just looking for a simpler pattern for command query separation that does not involve events. If you're aware of one let me know please.

Comment: @Him Well, I've made you to read about CQRS but I wasn't thinking about suggesting you to implement a full CQRS... Miss the part of events or other complex things, and you can just focus on dropping data overtime in another table(s) that could be easily mapped so you can get one or many `BidderInfo` using your OR/M and get all associations already loadable (they would be loaded using lazy-loading)

Comment: @Him About moving that logic into the service layer, it's what I was advising you in my answer, it's the right solution in terms of software architecture and a clear separation of concerns and not violating the single responsibility principle. If there're **not** perfomance bottlenecks, go this way and you'll optimize everything or some part of the solution once you've detected a performance problem

Comment: Yes, I followed your tip in the answer, thanks again mate. (ie. I am not a programmer really, I am just learning)

Comment: @Him No problem! I really enjoyed this :) You might want to visit [DesignPatternNINJA](http://designpattern.ninja/). It's a site where I publish interesting articles about software architecture and development, and I'm also creating a catalog of patterns and anti-patterns. For example, I've documented the repository pattern in two flavors: [Repository](http://designpattern.ninja/catalog/design-patterns/repository) and [Agnostic Repository](http://designpattern.ninja/catalog/design-patterns/agnostic-repository).

Comment: @Him I hope you may enjoy that site!

Comment: @Him Oh! And yesterday I published an article that might be of your interest: [Powerful generalizations using C# extension methods, generics and interfaces](http://designpattern.ninja/news/2017/02/19/powerful-generalizations-with-c-extension-methods-and-interfaces)

Comment: I will surely spend the few coming hours on reading your articles :D please stop making me read stuff hahahahaha

Comment: @Him And I've this this this this this and this, and this, and this, and this!! hahahaha Thank you. Probably not all articles might be of your interest... but there're some "invented" patterns that you might want to consider.  Thank you again and welcome to the club :D